# Polling using Websockets Unable to Communicate [Integrated with AWS]

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io

Client Side:

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = openSocket(‘https://url/', {
transports: ['polling', 'websocket', 'flashsocket']
});
function onQueueUpdated(callback) {
socket.on('queue update', callback);
}
export {
onQueueUpdated
};
```

Server Side:

```
var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(path.resolve('.'), secret.key')),
cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(path.resolve('.'), ‘certi.crt')),
ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(path.resolve('.'), ‘ca.crt')),
requestCert: false,
rejectUnauthorized: false
};
app.set("port", 8443);
server = https.createServer(options, app);
io = SocketIO(server);
io.set('origins', '*:*’);
server.listen(8443);
```

Its working fine on my local but When executed on AWS creates an issue

Error states:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DPRT.png)